# How to run AdamJ's WSUS Automated Maintenance script on Server 2016 Core

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2016

My WSUS server runs Server 2016 Core edition without a GUI so everything must be installed via powershell. When I run `Adamj_Clean-WSUS.ps1 -FirstRun` the errors are:

`The term 'sqlcmd' is not recognized...`

```
Executing ComputerObjectCleanup
Executing WSUSDBMaintenance
11     Job11           BackgroundJob   Failed        False           localhost            sqlcmd -S np:\\.\pipe\...
The term 'sqlcmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet...

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\user\Documents\Adamj_Clean-WSUS.ps1:2480 char:9
...
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\user\Documents\Adamj_Clean-WSUS.ps1:2482 char:9
+         $Script:AdamjWSUSDBMaintenanceOutputHTML += $AdamjWSUSDBMaint ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Executing WSUSServerCleanupWizard
_
```

Had to kill the window to stop this after it ran for several hours.

Comment: Hint: What would you need to install for `sqlcmd` to be a valid command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Download the ODBC driver and the SQL Command Line Utilities

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/system-requirements-installation-and-driver-files#installing-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility

### Copy files to the core server

One method is to place them into a share on another server then mount that share:

```
New-PSDrive -Name T -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\<server_IP>\<share_name> -Credential <domain>\<user>
cp T:\<folder>\msodbcsql.msi.msi .
cp T:\<folder>\MsSqlCmdLnUtils.msi .
cp T:\<folder>\Clean-WSUS.ps1 .
```

### How to install msi files

If you're used to hitting the **tab** key for filename completion and think a ".\" automatically prepended to a filename is innocent, be aware it is not: https://superuser.com/a/1310787/891171

### Install odbc driver

```
msiexec /i msodbcsql.msi /qn IACCEPTMSODBCSQLLICENSETERMS=YES /L*V msodbcsql.log
```

verify log:

```
Get-Content -path .\msodbcsql.log
```

### Install sqlcmd

```
msiexec /i MsSqlCmdLnUtils.msi /Passive /NoRestart IACCEPTMSSQLCMDLNUTILSLICENSETERMS=YES /L*V MsSqlCmdLnUtils.log
```

verify log:

```
Get-Content -path .\MsSqlCmdLnUtils.log
```

### Set path

This is where my SQLCMD.EXE was installed. YMMV:

```
$env:Path += ";C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\"
```

### Execute the script

As noted within the script (you did read the comments and set your variables already, right?), run this first:

```
PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
```

Then:

```
Clean-WSUS.ps1 -FirstRun
```